# Cosa sono le "strade a ruota"?

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *Il sorriso dell'ignoto marinaio*, di Vincenzo Consolo, ho letto questo testo proveniente dell'*[Archivio di Stato di Palermo, Carte della Polizia](https://archive.org/stream/CospirazioniERivolteDiFrancescoBentivegnaECompagni/Cospirazioni_e_rivolte_di_Francesco_Bent_djvu.txt)* (1857):

> «Accusati tutti cinque di misfatti di lesa maestà e precisamente di aver cospirato contro il Real Governo e di aver eccitato con banda armata, con bandiera tricolore sventolata, ed a suon di tamburo i sudditi ad armarsi contro l'Autorità Reale in Cefalù e diversi Comuni del Distretto, frangendo Stemmi Reali ed immaginidei nostri amatissimi Sovrani; espilate le casse Regie, abbattuti i telegrafi; sequestrate le valigie dei Regi corrieri, dissacrandone le lettere; arrestati i funzionari Regi; disarmata la forza pubblica; impiantata la bandiera rivoltosa sul bastione della marina di Cefalù a vista del vapore Regio, veniente in quella rada, devastazione, saccheggio ed incendio alla Sottointendenza e palazzo del Sottointendente di Cefalù, sperdendo, bruciando carte e registri, involato quintali due e rotoli 69 di polvere agli impiegati delle **strade a ruota** per uso di far saltare macigni, da ultimo di aver fatto resistenza alla forza pubblica, facendo fuoco per 9 ore continue in Pettineo, provincia di Messina».

Sapreste spiegarmi qual è il significato di "strada a ruota"? Ho cercato alle voci "strada" e "ruota" in parecchi dizionari, ma non ho trovato questa locuzione. Da quello che si legge in [questo testo dell'Ottocento](https://books.google.es/books?id=XhZEAAAAYAAJ&pg=RA1-PA49&dq=%22strada+a+ruota%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjqnLS4qtPbAhUFxxQKHQV3AW0Q6AEIJDAF#v=onepage&q=%22strada%20a%20ruota%22&f=false) si può dedurre che il significato sarebbe lo stesso di "strada carrozzabile" in contrapposizione alla "strada di ferro" o "ferrovia"?

Comment: La tua deduzione, @Charo, mi sembra corretta. A quanto ne so, «strada a ruota» non è un'espressione comune.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nel volume *[Opere](http://www.unibesa.it/images/IgnazioGattusoOpereI.pdf)* di Ignazio Gattuso, nelle pagg. 105-106 c'è un riferimento preciso alle vie di comunicazione nella Sicilia di metà ottocento, e in particolare alle ***strade a ruota*** e alla loro diffusione:

> **Le strade a ruota**
>  "Fin oltre la metà dello scorso secolo — scriveva Giuseppe Perez nel 1861 — e perciò fino alla prima metà del
>   700 la Sicilia mancava quasi intieramente di vie atte alle ruote. Il
>   commercio interno, che consisteva principalmente in quello del grano e
>   dell' olio faceasi per mezzo di animali da soma, ed in particolare i
>   muli, come praticasi tuttora nei paesi che sono sprovveduti di strade
>   (quel "tuttora" possiamo, in gran parte,  ripeterlo ancora oggi).
>
> Le nuove arterie più large e più comode, non per nulla nominate
>   "***strade a ruota***", incrementarono i trasporti con carri e i
>   viaggi con carrozze fino allora di scarso numero nelle città.

Il significato di strade a ruota è quindi quello di strade [carrozzabili](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/carrozzabile/), cioè:

> Di strada che può essere agevolmente percorsa in carrozza;